# Adding predicate to a map function

Tags: haskell, dictionary, filtering

Completely new to Haskell and learning through Learn Haskell the greater good.

I am looking at the map function

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]  
map _ [] = []  
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

is it possible to add a predicate to this? for example, to only map to every other element in the list?

Comment: Have you had a look at `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`?

Comment: Are you looking for `nub`, which removes the duplicates of a list?

Comment: I am currently looking at filter C Quilley, How do I apply it?

F Boller. I am looking to do somthing like this mapEveryOther (+100) [1,2,3,4,5] and output be [101,2,103,4,105]

Comment: If you're looking for a function, which does it in one step, you're on the wrong road. Functional programming is more about combining functions than do it with one function with many parameters.

Comment: So I am looking to filter the list, map the filtered elements and then reform in a new list?

Comment: In your case, no, because the kind of mapping is dependend of the filter. I wrote an answer.

Comment: Please, do *not* put tags in the title. The title should be an English *sentence*, without random words such as `Bar, Baz: Something` or `This is a title (Baz)` etc. There is a specific section for tags; use that to categorize your question.

Comment: Regarding your question: the output of `mapEveryOther (+100) [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` should be `[102, 3, 104, 5, 106]` or `[2, 103, 4, 105, 6]`? I.e. do you care whether the number is `odd` or whether the number is on an `odd` position?

Comment: The number in an odd position

Comment: Or more specifically, every other number starting from the first element as a list can start with zero

Comment: Technically, I don't think 'mapping every other element in the list' can be done using a predicate since a predicate applies to the value, whereas you want to apply a predicate to the element's position in the list.

Answer (score 7):

You can code your own version of `map` to apply `f` only to even (or odd) positions as follows. (Below indices start from `0`)

```
mapEven :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEven f []     = []
mapEven f (x:xs) = f x : mapOdd f xs

mapOdd :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapOdd f []     = []
mapOdd f (x:xs) = x : mapEven f xs
```

If instead you want to exploit the library functions, you can do something like

```
mapEven :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEven f = map (\(flag,x) -> if flag then f x else x) . zip (cycle [True,False])
```

or even

```
mapEven :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEven f = map (uncurry (\flag -> if flag then f else id)) . zip (cycle [True,False])
```

If you want to filter using an arbitrary predicate on the index, then:

```
mapPred :: (Int -> Bool) -> (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapPred p f = map (\(i,x) -> if p i then f x else x) . zip [0..]
```

---

A more direct solution can be reached using `zipWith` (as @amalloy suggests).

```
mapEven :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEven f = zipWith (\flag x -> if flag then f x else x) (cycle [True,False])
```

This can be further refined as follows

```
mapEven :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEven f = zipWith ($) (cycle [f,id])
```

Comment: These solutions with `map . zip` look weird. I can understand including one of them for demonstrative purposes, but why not use `zipWith`?

Comment: @amalloy I added a `zipWith` alternative as well.

Answer (score 3):

The "canonical" way to perform filtering based on positions is to `zip` the sequence with the naturals, so as to append an index to each element:

```
> zip [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13] [0..]
[(1,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(5,4),(8,5),(13,6)]
```

This way you can filter the whole thing using the second part of the tuples, and then map a function which discards the indices:

```
indexedFilterMap p f xs = (map (\(x,_) -> f x)) . (filter (\(_,y) -> p y)) $ (zip xs [0..])
oddFibsPlusOne = indexedFilterMap odd (+1) [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

To be specific to you question, one might simply put

```
mapEveryOther f = indexedFilterMap odd f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map with a function (a lambda is also possible):

```
plusIfOdd :: Int -> Int
plusIfOdd a 
  | odd a = a
  | otherwise = a + 100

map plusIfOdd [1..5]
```

Comment: Since you name it, it might be noteworthy here that any function _is_ a lambda! Your code is syntactic sugar for `plusIfOdd = \a -> if odd a then a else a + 100`.

Comment: This increases the odd numbers, not the numbers at odd positions, though.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, write the function for what you want to do to the individual element of the list:

```
applytoOdd :: Integral a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
applytoOdd f x = if odd x
                 then (f x)
                 else x
```

So `applytoOdd` function will apply the function `f` to the element if the element is odd or else return the same element if it is even. Now you can apply `map` to that like this:

```
λ> let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
λ> map (applytoOdd (+ 100)) a
[101,2,103,4,105]
```

Or if you want to add `200` to it, then:

```
λ> map (applytoOdd (+ 200)) a
[201,2,203,4,205]
```

---

Looking on the comments, it seems you want to `map` based on the index position. You can modify your `applytoOdd` method appropriately for that:

```
applytoOdd :: Integral a => (b -> b) -> (a, b) -> b
applytoOdd f (x,y) = if odd x
                     then (f y)
                     else y
```

Here, the type variable `a` corresponds to the index element. If it's odd you are applying the function to the actual element of the list. And then in ghci:

```
λ> map (applytoOdd (+ 100)) (zip [1..5] [1..])
[101,2,103,4,105]
λ> map (applytoOdd (+ 200)) (zip [1..5] [1..])
[201,2,203,4,205]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use a list comprehension:

```
mapOdd f x = if odd x then f x else x
[ mapOdd (+100) x | x <- [1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad that you're taking the time to learn about Haskell. It's an amazing language. However it does require you to develop a certain mindset. So here's what I do when I face a problem in Haskell. Let's start with your problem statement:

> Is it possible to add a predicate to the `map` function? For example, to only `map` to every other element in the list?

So you have two questions:

1. Is it possible to add a predicate to the `map` function?
2. How to `map` to every other element in the list?

So the way people think in Haskell is via type signatures. For example, when an engineer is designing a building she visualizes how the building should look for the top (top view), the front (front view) and the side (side view). Similarly when functional programmers write code they visualize their code in terms of type signatures.

Let's start with what we know (i.e. the type signature of the `map` function):

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Now you want to add a predicate to the `map` function. A predicate is a function of the type `a -> Bool`. Hence a `map` function with a predicate will be of the type:

```
mapP :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

However, in your case, you also want to keep the unmapped values. For example `mapP odd (+100) [1,2,3,4,5]` should result in `[101,2,103,4,105]` and not `[101,103,105]`. Hence it follows that the type of the input list should match the type of the output list (i.e. `a` and `b` must be of the same type). Hence `mapP` should be of the type:

```
mapP :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
```

It's easy to implement a function like this:

```
map :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapP p f = map (\x -> if p x then f x else x)
```

---

Now to answer your second question (i.e. how to `map` to every other element in the list). You could use `zip` and `unzip` as follows:

```
snd . unzip . mapP (odd . fst) (fmap (+100)) $ zip [1..] [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Here's what's happening:

1. We first `zip` the index of each element with the element itself. Hence `zip [1..] [1,2,3,4,5]` results in `[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)]` where the `fst` value of each pair is the index.
2. For every `odd` index element we apply the `(+100)` function to the element. Hence the resulting list is `[(1,101),(2,2),(3,103),(4,4),(5,105)]`.
3. We `unzip` the list resulting in two separate lists `([1,2,3,4,5],[101,2,103,4,105])`.
4. We discard the list of indices and keep the list of mapped results using `snd`.

We can make this function more general. The type signature of the resulting function would be:

```
mapI :: ((Int, a) -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The definition of the `mapI` function is simple enough:

```
mapI :: ((Int, a) -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapI p f = snd . unzip . mapP p (fmap f) . zip [1..]
```

You can use it as follows:

```
mapI (odd . fst) (+100) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add a predicate to this? for example, to only map to every other element in the list?

Yes, but functions should ideally do one relatively simple thing only.  If you need to do something more complicated, ideally you should try doing it by composing two or more functions.

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, so I'll show a few examples.  First: if what you mean is that you only want to map in cases where a supplied predicate returns true of the input element, but otherwise just leave it alone, then you can do that by reusing the `map` function:

```
mapIfTrue :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapIfTrue pred f xs = map step xs
   where step x | pred x    = f x
                | otherwise = x
```

If what you mean is that you want to discard list elements that don't satisfy the predicate, and apply the function to the remaining ones, then you can do that by combining `map` and `filter`:

```
filterMap :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
filterMap pred f xs = map f (filter pred xs)
```

Mapping the function over every other element of the list is different from these two, because it's not a predicate over the elements of the list; it's either a *structural transformation* of the list of a *stateful traversal* of it.

Also, I'm not clear whether you mean to discard or keep the elements you're not applying the function to, which would imply different answers. If you're discarding them, then you can do it by just discarding alternate list elements and then mapping the function over the remaining ones:

```
keepEven :: [a] -> [a]
keepEven xs = step True xs
    where step _ [] = []
          step True (x:xs) = x : step False xs
          step False (_:xs) = step True xs

mapEven :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapEven f xs = map f (keepEven xs)
```

If you're keeping them, one way you could do it is by tagging each list element with its position, filtering the list to keep only the ones in even positions, discard the tags and then map the function:

```
-- Note: I'm calling the first element of a list index 0, and thus even.
mapEven :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEven f xs = map aux (filter evenIndex (zip [0..] xs))
    where evenIndex (i, _) = even i
          aux (_, x) = f x
```

As another answer mentioned, `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]` combines two lists pairwise by position.

But this is the general philosophy: to do a complex thing, use a combination of general-purpose generic functions.  If you're familiar with Unix, it's similar to that.

---

Another simple way to write the last one.  It's longer, but keep in mind that `evens`, `odds` and `interleave` all are generic and reusable:

```
evens, odds :: [a] -> [a]
evens = alternate True
odds = alternate False

alternate :: Bool -> [a] -> [a]
alternate _ [] = []
alternate True (x:xs) = x : alternate False xs
alternate False (_:xs) = alternate True xs

interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave [] ys = ys
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs

mapEven :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEven f xs = interleave (map f (evens xs)) (odds xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a predicate because predicates operate on list values, not their indices.

I quite like this format for what you're trying to do, since it makes the case handling quite clear for the function:

```
newMap :: (t -> t) -> [t] -> [t]
newMap f [] = [] -- no items in list
newMap f [x] = [f x] -- one item in list
newMap f (x:y:xs) = (f x) : y : newMap f xs -- 2 or more items in list
```

For example, running:

```
newMap (\x -> x + 1) [1,2,3,4]
```

Yields:

```
[2,2,4,4]
```